# Blank data is inserted in PostgreSQL using Laravel

Tags: php, ajax, postgresql, laravel, laravel-5

I am just starting to use laravel, but I am stacked on this part, in which I cannot successfully saved the user inputted data in the database using PostgreSQl because it just shows blank entries aside from id and its timestamps. Why is it that blank data is inserted in my database fields using Laravel? Here are my codes:

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 $(".submit-prod").click(function(e){

 e.preventDefault();

   $.post("{{ url('/addprod') }}",$("#prod-form").serialize(),function(data) {

       if(data.notify == "Success"){
         console.log(data.notify);
       }

    },"json");

}); //end
```

**Route.php**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {

Route::auth();

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::any('addprod', 'Product\ProductController@store');

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
});
```

**ProductController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Product;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Product\Product as Product;

class ProductController extends Controller
{

/**
 * Show the application dashboard.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index()
{
    return view('home');
}

public function store(Request $request){

    $products = Product::create($request->all());


      if($products){

        $notification = "Success";

      } else{
        $notification = "Failed";
      }

      return json_encode(array('notify'=>$notification));

    }
  }
```

**Model(Product.php)**

```
<?php

 namespace App\Product;

 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

 class Product extends Model
 {
  //
 }
```

**Output (Blank fields)**

[image: A screenshot of the empty fields in the PostgreSQL database]

Comment: Please help me with this. Any help pls.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable mass assignment for columns you want to fill in your model.
For example:

```
 namespace App\Product;

 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

 class Product extends Model
 {
  protected $fillable = ['quantity'];
 }
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#mass-assignment

Then in your controller store() method:

```
$product = new Product();
$product->fill($request->all())->save();
```

Comment: already done that, but still blank :( pls help me. I am almost searching for a day just to have answer for this but no luck at all.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a Laravel expert will come along and spot the error. Until then, try locating it by following the data as it's passed from frontend to backend to database.
Is all the data actually being sent by the browser and received by the server?

Does this fire when you post data?

```
   if(data.notify == "Success"){
     console.log(data.notify);
   }
```

Keep the debugger's network tab open when you post data and make sure that  it's all being sent.

Try returning/echoing the entire post data back to the browser by changing this line:

```
return json_encode(array('notify'=>$notification));
```

A shot in the dark: What happens if you remove the "json" at the end of your javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Should you learn before blindly try. Maybe, standard request first ajax then because there are some issues with csrf tokens.

You need the fillable fields to be set:

```
class Product extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['unit', 'price', etc...;
```

I recommend you this series: [laracasts.com](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/)